# Line Matches Stringpart -> Insert String before last three Characters of Line

Tags: javascript, powershell, thunderbird

I want to find a line in a JS config file and insert a string before the last three characters.

Let's start with an example snippet (account amounts are varying also their numbers):

```js
...
user_pref("mail.account.lastKey", 10);
user_pref("mail.accountmanager.accounts", "account1,account2,account14,account5");
user_pref("mail.accountmanager.defaultaccount", "account1");
...
```

The function has to find the pattern `user_pref("mail.accountmanager.accounts"`.
After the pattern different amounts of accounts follows with unknown numbers eg.: *account1,account3,account10* or *account1,account12,account13,account15*

My aim is to append an *account* String with a number e.g. *account74* at the end of the last given account.
The only similarity from all different config files is the beginning of the line, `user_pref...` and the end of the line: `");`.

### Background

This Function is taking action in a PowerShell script for an implementation to "Prefs.js".

### Code

My function looks like this in detail:

```cs
$number        = 74
$FileName      = "C:\Path\to\prefs.js"
$MatchString   = '"mail.accountmanager.accounts",'
$ReplaceString = "`"\);"
$NewString     = ",account$number`");"

function AccountAppender {
    (Get-Content $FileName) | ForEach-Object {
        $_
        if ($_ -match $MatchString) {
            $_ -replace $ReplaceString, $NewString
        }
    } 
    | Set-Content $FileName
}

AccountAppender
```

Other thought with replace operator:

```cs
$number                 = 74
$SearchContentAccount   = '"mail.accountmanager.accounts",'
$AddContentAccount      = @"
,account$number"); 
"@
$AccountStringRaw       = Get-Content -Path $Filename |
                          Select-String -Pattern $SearchContentAccount
$AccountStringLastChars = $AccountStringRaw.Substring($AccountStringRaw.Length -3)
$AccountStringReplacer  = $AccountStringLastChars.Replace('");',$AddContentAccount)
```

### Expectation & Reality

My current problem is that that the result line will be appended on a new line with the new "inserted" string. Instead of this I want the old line to be replaced.

At the moment I got this:

```js
...
user_pref("mail.accountmanager.accounts", "account1,account2");
user_pref("mail.accountmanager.accounts", "account1,account2,account74");
...
```

I want to get this kind of result:

```js
...
user_pref("mail.accountmanager.accounts", "account1,account2,account74");
...
```

---

### Question:

How can I correctly Pipe the commands to replace the target line with the new line which contains the appended account?

Or otherwise: Is there an option (command pipeline with replace, insert, pattern or match) to find the line with the pattern part, get the full line as `$PSItem`, then jump to the third from last character and add the new string?

Comment: ``(Get-Content 'prefs.js') -replace '(user_pref\("mail.accountmanager.accounts", ".*)("\);)', "`$1,$NewString`$2" | Set-Content 'prefs.js'``

Comment: Many Thanks Mr Wiechers - I appreciate your Answer regarding my concern :-)